# Make only the Player class have input functions using an interface in Java

Tags: java, object

I am trying to make a Space Invaders clone.

At the moment, all objects are implementing an interface called "Drawable" that allows me to control them. however, I'm wanting my player class to control user input from inside the class, not from a global variable that the object sets.

I currently have an interface called "Drawble" that looks like this:

```
interface Drawable{
  public Rectangle getRect();
  public void setRect(Rectangle temprect);
  public boolean callBeforeTick();
  public boolean callTick();
  public boolean callAfterTick();
  public void Draw(Graphics g);
  public boolean rectIntersect(Rectangle temprect,String tempname);
  public String getName();
  public int getX();
  public int getY();
  public void setPos(int tempX,int tempY);
}
```

All objects that I have are in the array "DrawableStuff" and spawning code looks like this:

```
public static void spawnObjects(){
  DrawableStuff.add(new Player(90,560,20,20)); // spawn player object
  // spawn shield object
    for (int j=150; j<=800; j+=150){
        for (int i=j; i<=j+40; i+=10){
            for (int k=500;k<=520; k+=10){
                DrawableStuff.add(new Shield(i,k));
            }
        }
    }
    // spawn ship object
    for (int i=100; i<=400; i+=30){
        for (int k=40;k<=160; k+=30){
            DrawableStuff.add(new Ship(i,k));
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, the way how I create the "Cannonshot" is by making the "Player" object modify a global variable then the main code handles it, like this:

```
if (Drawer.fireNow&&Drawer.fireTimer==0){
        Drawer.fireTimer=10;
        Drawer.DrawableStuff.add(new Cannonshot((int)playerX+9,(int)playerY-5));
    }
  if (Drawer.fireTimer>0){
    Drawer.fireTimer-=1;
  }
```

I'm modifying the objects using code that looks like this (the Draw code looks something like this, too):

```
for (Iterator<Drawable> i = DrawableStuff.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Drawable d = i.next();
          d.callTick();
      }
```

I'm wanting ONLY the Player to have to have inputPressed, inputReleased, and inputHeld. however, with the way I'm currently doing it, it would mean I would have to add those functions to all my classes. Can anyone offer advice on how to do this, please? :)

Comment: You create a second interface with the inputPressed, inputReleased, and inputHeld methods.  Your Player class can implement both interfaces.  Your code doesn't look very extendable.  Take a look at my article [Horse Race GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=425) to see how I put together a Swing game using the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I've added an extra interface to the Player class, but I can't figure out how to call the inputPressed + others. Do I need to create another array? how do I do it? please help. :)